# Custom search pattern in VIM

Tags: search, vim, parameters

In what way I can make sort of a shortcut to parametrized search in vim? So when I invoke (for example) `:customsearch foo`, I get a search for `/bar foo baz$`. Or more generally `/bar %s baz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a command to the vimrc file such as this:

Note that the command must start with a capital letter.

```
command -nargs=1 Customsearch :
    \ /foo <args> baz
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to create a custom shortcut out of it? like `f/ foo` or `sf foo` (or similar) to mean `:Customsearch foo`? And (optionally, if it's not unnecessarily complicated), to update the search in real time as I type in the keyword?

Answer (score 4):

@TonyMyddeltyn's answer shows a custom command, which is a valid approach. As you're asking for a shortcut mapping and real-time display, you can have that by defining an *incomplete* search mapping.

Think of first preparing the search (with parameters already inserted and the cursor placed in the middle), and then completing it by filling in the blanks and triggering searching via <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That first part can be supplied by a mapping, like this:

```
:nnoremap sf /bar  baz$<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```