# Trim tabs at the end of a search query - VIM

Tags: vim

I use vim for most of my editing but from other places, I have the habit of tab to complete.
This means when searching in vim I often append a tab character to my search without thinking.
This is particularly the case when searching in netrw when I'm searching not based on the first few characters of the file.

```
/thefile^I
```

It then doesn't match obviously.
Is there any way to have trailing space trimmed from search and furthermore trimmed only from search in netrw?

I'd like it to be from the standard search rather than a new search command as is shown in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751998/custom-search-pattern-in-vim)

Comment: There is no such thing as "explore mode".

Comment: What is the thing called you get to when :Ex

Comment: It's called Netrw: `:help netrw`.

Comment: Thank you I've corrected the question

Comment: Downvoted or not, the solution to a problem caused by bad habits is not to find technological solutions that make them ineffective, as that only reinforces them. It is to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I should have posted this in the vim exchange instead. To which I got the following response which works a treat.

```
cnoremap <expr> <CR> index(['/', '?'], getcmdtype()) > -1 ? "<C-\>esubstitute(getcmdline(), '\t$', '', '')<CR><CR>" : "<CR>"
```

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/trim-tabs-at-the-end-of-a-search-query/36889#36889